# Python requests verify self-signed certificate

Tags: python, python-requests, certificate, self-signed, verify

Hoping someone can prevent me from having a mental breakdown ...

I am using the python requests module to consume a web API written in .NET (Windows). I have set myself up as my own CA and signed a server CSR (to do this I followed a good tutorial at https://realpython.com/python-https/#reader-comments). I package the resulting signed certificate with the server.

What happened next:

- I try to access the API in Chrome (running through localhost). Doesn't work. As expected.
- I add the CA certificate (which is self-signed) to my trusted root CAs in Chrome. Works. As expected.

Now I go to python:

- I call requests.get with the 'verify' parameter pointing to the CA certificate. Does not work. Complains that the certificate is self-signed.
- If I point 'verify' to the actual signed server certificate however ... it works.

Perhaps everything is fine, but my question is this:

From much of what I've read, including, especially, the aforementioned tutorial, you should just be able to point 'verify' at the CA certificate alone (rather than the signed server certificate). Is this right? Or is the behaviour I am seeing in my case the expected behaviour?

Thanks for any help you might be able to give. I realise I have posted no code. That can follow if there is indeed an issue with the way that I am doing things.

**Update**

So, on Ubuntu, requests can be verified with the CA certificate alone. The tutorial I was following was written for Linux users. The 'issue' I attempted to describe above is specific to running on windows.

Comment: A self-signed certificate is the opposite of a CA signed certificate (even if you created the CA certificate on your own). Your question is a bit unclear on what you actually have.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm new to this field, so my lingo might have gone awry. But what I meant was that the 'CA certificate' (which I've created myself), which I use to sign my CSRs, is self-signed (subject = issuer). Does that make sense? If not, I'll have to drop a code bomb.